# OpenCV build error

Tags: opencv, cygwin

If this is not out of place here, would like to know about the source and fix for an error I get when I am building OpenCV under Cygwin (On Windows 7 64 bit).

I have Cygwin installed with MingW- pthread pacgae installed in that cygwin installation.

I have downloaded OpenCV ver. 2.3.1 source package.

**EDIT:**

After some tweaks, and changes to build process OpenCV builds fine now.
But when I compile a simple test openCV code(C source code), as below it gives lot of linker errors of undefined references to many basic openCV functions. I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly but still errors persit:

```
cc -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -/usr/local/include/opencv -lop                                                                                                                encv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_calib3d test1.c -o test_op                                                                                                                encv
cc: unrecognized option '-/usr/local/include/opencv'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x9dd): undefined reference to `_cvFree_'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0xa4e): undefined reference to `_cvFree_'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `_cvGetRows'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0xb6f): undefined reference to `_cvGetCols'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0xb82): undefined reference to `_cvReleaseMat'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0xcd2): undefined reference to `_cvAddS'

/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x1137): undefined reference to `_cvRead'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x11e1): undefined reference to `_cvLoadImage'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x129d): undefined reference to `_cvCreateImage'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x12dd): undefined reference to `_cvResize'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x12f1): undefined reference to `_cvNamedWindow'
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x1305): undefined reference to `_cvNamedWindow'
                                           '
/tmp/ccfEqFK0.o:test1.c:(.text+0x13ad): undefined reference to `_cvDestroyWindow
```

... ... Many more undefined references.

```
                              '
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:10: recipe for target `test_opencv' failed
make: *** [test_opencv] Error 1
```

**EDIT**

Below message is still there, but it is not an error but a message during build process.

*Then while building OpenCV under cygwin, when I do make , it gives a error message
    c++: unrecognized option '-pthread'
    [ 36%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_sunras.o*

and for many other files i see the same error `c++: unrecognized option '-pthread'`

I would like to know if anyone has experience in building openCV under Cygwin , how to get OpenCV going under cygwin? . Now I know there is windows setup for OpenCV but that is not what is an option to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointers:
What I found was the problem was as follows:

In my Makefile of my openCV test app I was linking with the import libraries (*.a). Which was the problem.

Problematic Makefile was linking against files

```
-l:/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dll.a ...etc...
```

I changed that to link with actual dll libs, then it worked(linked) fine, w/o any errors as above.

Changes Makefile looks:

```
LIBS = -l:/usr/local/bin/cygopencv_core-2.3.dll -l:/usr/local/bin/cygopencv_imgproc-2.3.dll -l:/usr/local/bin/cygopencv_highgui-2.3.dll -l:/usr/local/bin/cygopencv_video-2.3.dll -l:/usr/local/bin/cygopencv_calib3d-2.3.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cmd line arguments has a few problems. It seems that it was not fully pasted in your question (some indentation problems suggests so).

- One obvious mistake can be easily identified since CC is telling you about it:  `cc: unrecognized option '-/usr/local/include/opencv'`:

When adding headers directories in the command line, you must specify each of them with **`-I`**. Notice how you failed to do so with: `-/usr/local/include/opencv`. It should be `-I/usr/local/include/opencv`

- You also seem to be missing `-lopencv_core` in the cmd-line

In the future, use **pkg-config** (if its properly configured) to help you include opencv headers and libraries:

```
cc test.c -o test_op `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lop
```